# Unity disappear when I activate Nvidia driver for 8500 GT

Tags: drivers

I'm new to linux, I've installed ubuntu 12.10 and install Nvidia driver for 8500 GT.
After the restart unity disappear, all what I see is the desktop, no top menu no dash.
I've tried to install all available drivers, but I get the same issu.
So what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Hey I had the same problem after I switched to the official Nvidia proprietary drivers but when I installed the latest generic linux headers everything went back to normal. Try this and restart

> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic

Hope this helped.

Comment: Actually I  installed the third driver then the whole graphic system disappear, what i got only command line.
I tried to install gnome, but can't log in to graphical mode, so I installed a fresh version of ubuntu, even now i can't understand what wrong I made :)

Answer (score -1):

First step, right click on your desktop then select 'open terminal'
If you haven't installed `unity-tweak` before you should install it first.

```
$ sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool  
$ unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Comment: I don't think there is reason to reset Unity! In my experience this particular problem occurs because the driver is not properly installed/loaded. Your suggestion will reset all Unity settings to their defaults, which is probably not what OP desires.

Comment: It's OK on ubuntu 15.04 after I installed nvidia driver 346.59 and then reboot computer. My ubuntu showed desktop only, don't have unity. I reset by uninstall nvidia driver to intel driver but now unity remain disappeared. I search and found something then test it with that command. Oh! My unity comes here. It's appeared again. I posted it when I found the right way to fix that issue. I learned something on Stackoverflow.com which you should test before post something. Don't think and post or search on web then post it.

Comment: About that you comment, My Unity doesn't go to default. It comes with my all setting my icons and my theme.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I understand, you will need to recompile the kernel as well if you wish to use the graphics card to the fullest capacity. Go to nvidia website and download ur driver file.

Comment: That is not true.The proprietary GPU drivers are not compiled into the kernel but made available through modules on runtime, usually through DKMS. The nVidia driver installation program will build a DKMS model and insert it into the DKMS tree.